# how to analyse and predict(machine learning) a time series data set using scikit-learn for python

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, classification, scikit-learn

i got data-set like this

[image: data set]

i need to analyse and predict the status column. This is just 2 entrees from the training data set. In this data set there is heart rate pattern(which is collected in 1 second intervals, 10 numbers altogether) its a time series array(correct me if i'm wrong) i just need to know best way to analyse and get a prediction using this data. I'm using scikit-learning for my data-mining and machine learning.

What i just want to know is what is the best way to analyse these time series data? should i use vector based approach or something else. If you can give me example code that would be great for me to understand it.

Comment: Vector based is totally legit. You may want to normalize given your problem. You may also want to look into that : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping

Comment: The question is too broad, I believe. Could you please put a bit of the data set and a tentative code section here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feed in each point in the heart rate time series as a separate column, along with a separate column (feature) for all of the the other data points. Do feature normalization (substract the mean, divide by the standard deviation) for each column over the entire dataset, and feed into a classifier.

Comment: what is the meaning of doing that? Could you explain me how it will optimize the mining.?

Comment: It will allow the sklearn algorithms to process it in a vector form, and also consider correlations between points at different times in the past. You may also want to consider adding some features that are moving averages of the different types of inputs, although I am not sure how well that fits in with your particular dataset.